# GRUB2 failed with 'No video mode activated'

Tags: grub2, luks

I've installed Ubuntu-Alternate 11.04 to use the encrypted feature.

All works fine, but rebooting the system ended up in an error-message:

```
Error: No video mode activated'
```

Reading some threads I guess, GRUB wants to read something, especially fonts, from the encrypted device.

Is this a known error and does an solution exists.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, Grub2 is trying to load some fonts and cannot because they are located on the encrypted partition.

The bugreport + fix are located here :

FIX on comment #24 from Guido Nickels
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/699802

If you don't want to scroll, just cut & paste :

`sudo cp /usr/share/grub/*.pf2 /boot/grub/ && sudo update-grub`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In the file /etc/default/grub find and turn off (comment with "#") two lines:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

After this run update-grub.
This method together with the previous advice of jflaflamme was helped me.