# How can I disable graphical boot, yet start x during boot?

Tags: boot, nvidia, graphics, xorg, plymouth

## My question

I am not attached to the splashscreen or whatever. **How can I configure a non-graphical boot that still takes me to the login screen?** In other words, I do want X to start as the last thing in the boot process, but I do not need any other tools (plymouth or userspace bootsplash or whatever).

## My problem

I get a blank/purple screen at undefined times when use the battery or when I have used it. I have a Lenovo Easypad z580. At times the problem also occurs after a suspend. In that case it states something like `userspace bootsplash stopped`.

## My research

I read and tried the solutions in the following pages:

1. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen
2. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze
3. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/NonGraphicalBoot
4. [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I already disabled plymouth.

I do not think that this question is a duplicate (because I want a non-graphical boot, yet a graphical desktop). But I might be mistaking. Also my scenario is none of the ones proposed in [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) (If you are trying to install Ubuntu, If you have a dual boot system, If an update or something else caused your problem).

Comment: Do yo tried to start Ubuntu choosing recover mode in grub? Starts without X and you can try to solve your problem installing drivers etc...

Comment: Hi smile. I am not sure this is a drivers issue. Also recovery mode is not really what I am looking for.

Comment: Just to understand what you want: 1) you want the normal graphical greeter/login, 2) you don't want any graphical gimmicks until lightdm (or whichever display manger) starts.

Comment: Guntbert, that is indeed what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Uncomment `GRUB_TERMINAL="console"`

And remove `quiet splash` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

then issue `sudo update-grub`. This will disable graphical boot.

Comment: will this still `startx`?

Comment: there will be a text based boot, and it will take you to the lightdm login screen. will this still startx? i don't understand, if you want that startx appearing for login, then you have to disable lightdm.

Comment: if you already have startx, then just uncomment the GRUB_TERMINAL="console", (remove the number sign at the beginning) and you are good to go.

Comment: Ok that almost gets me there. When booting I now see `error: no video mode activated`.

Comment: there are many workaround for this bug (no video mode) here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/699802. might be an issue with gfxmode, fonts, grub hidden timeout etc

Comment: see this one too, many people have this problem.....http://askubuntu.com/questions/43196/grub2-failed-with-no-video-mode-activated