# Ubuntu 15.10 startup error

Tags: boot

I updated from 15.04 to 15.10. When I start up the computer I see

```
Error: no video mode activated
```

After this, it goes to the Ubuntu startup page with the logo but after load shows me a list of services that have started and stays on that screen. I am getting very frustrated. Ubuntu left a message saying that 15.04 will no longer receive updates and I should switch, and this version is broken upon arrival.

I can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> command to put in commands but have no idea where to start. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug. Maybe you can boot from the Livecd, and try to reinstall GRUB.

- Use live cd and choose to install Ubuntu.
- Don't Format partitions
  already created.
- Chose mount point for each partition, and then select continue. The
  grub installer will be reinstalled correctly.

Or Try to Commit: _GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_ and _GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET_ in */etc/default/grub* will help on this: Then try to run '*sudo update-grub*' after changes to /etc/default/grub.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=GRUB_SAVED_DEFAULT
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10 
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET= 
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: I am unsure if this alone would have fixed my issue as I also copied font files as described at https://askubuntu.com/a/83736/67747 - together those fixed my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Especially if you run an encrypted drive and you have nvidia drivers installed then you can try:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/699802

```bash
sudo cp /usr/share/grub/*.pf2  /boot/grub
sudo update-grub
```